# Points of continuity of Baire class one functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

This is an idle question motivated by two comments I made to a previous MO question (which I just searched for, unsuccessfully).  That question asked if the characteristic function of the rationals is a pointwise limit of continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

My first reply was that the answer is no: a function is said to be of **Baire class one** if it is a pointwise limit of continuous functions, and (so I remembered) every Baire class one function has a dense set of points of continuity, whereas of course $\bf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is discontinuous everywhere.

Then I checked up on this result (I am not an analyst, if that is not already clear) and realized that I had misremembered it slightly: the **Baire Characterization Theorem** says that a real function is of Baire class one iff for every nonempty closed subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, the restriction of $f$ to $S$ has at least one point of continuity.  (Note that in my comment I required that $S$ be perfect, i.e., without isolated points, because some sources state it this way.  This hypothesis is however superfluous because an isolated point of a topological space is a point of continuity for every real-valued function on that space.)  Taking $S = [a,b]$, we find that either (i) our BC1 function restricted to $S$ is continuous at $c \in (a,b)$ -- meaning that $f$ itself is continuous at $c$, since $S$ is a neighborhood of $c$ -- or (ii) $f|_S$ is continuous at $a$ -- meaning that $f$ itself is *right*-continuous at $a$, or finally (iii) $f|_S$ is continuous at $b$ -- so $f$ itself is *left*-continuous at $b$.  So we find that any BC1 function has a dense set of points at which it is either left-continuous or right-continuous (or both).  This is good enough to answer the question because $\bf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ has no points of left- or right-continuity.

But later I wondered whether my original claim was actually incorrect:

> Do there exist BC1 functions for which the set of points of continuity is not dense?  Or even empty?

I did of course try looking on the internet, but I didn't find a reference which gave a solid treatment of Baire classes of real functions: could someone supply one?  Moreover, I do see that by taking intervals of the form $(-\infty,b]$ and $[a,\infty)$ a BC1 function must have infinitely many points at which it is left-continuous and infinitely many points at which it is right-continuous.  And then I got stumped.  Probably this is in the category of things that were much better understood almost one hundred years ago than they are now...

Comment: @Pete : I think you were looking for http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31271/approximation-with-continuous-functions/ 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is impossible. Baire proved that if a function defined on $\mathbb R$ is of Baire class 1, then it is continuous everywhere except, possibly, for a [meagre set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set). And by another Baire's theorem a complement of a meagre set in $\mathbb R$ is dense.

An elementary exposition of this and related results can be found in the nice little [book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wUDjoT5xIFAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Oxtoby+measure+and+category&source=bl&ots=4ELHXUYSZJ&sig=Yyf8Xyg3ziUaiOubHvQNRaxrSa8&hl=en&ei=Lzw_TLqML9W7jAfM6_iUBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Oxtoby.

**Edit.** Another good reference which covers Baire's theorems and provides some historical background is ["The calculus gallery"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QnXSqvTiEjYC&dq=the+calculus+gallery&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=YIw_TNXGN6P00gTV5rCPBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by W. Dunham.

Comment: Could you give a reference?

Comment: Thanks very much.  So I must have seen this before and remembered it but then gotten a little nervous because the results of my google search did not quite match up with my memory.  MO to the rescue, as usual.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pity that these basic results are not mentioned in the related Wikipedia articles.

Comment: When I wrote a paper, First-Class Functions, for the Monthly nearly 20 years ago, I found the book, van Rooij and Schikhof, A Second Course on Real Functions, to be very useful. 

Comment: @Gerry: Thank you for the reference.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Baire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Baire_function&oldid=829038975)) mentions that "By another theorem of Baire, for every Baire-1 function the points of continuity are a comeager $G_\delta$ set" and gives [Theorem 24.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA193) in Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* as a reference.