# Possible subsets of reals that equal the set of continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

This should be an easy question, but I don't quite know how to approach it. It may be somewhat related to the concepts mentioned in the context of [this past question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32033/), though it was motivated mainly by the college calculus course I am teaching.

Question: Characterize those subsets *S* of the reals for which there exists a function *f* defined on the reals such that the set of points in the reals where *f* is continuous is precisely *S*.

Variant(s): Same as above, but we require *f* to be Borel (inverse images of Borel sets are Borel) or Lebesgue measurable (inverse images of Borel sets are measurable).

What I know:

1. If *S* is open, we can set *f* as the function that is 0 on *S*, 1 on the rationals outside *S* and -1 on the irrationals outside *S*. This is continuous only on *S*.
2. If *S* is closed, we can set *f* as follows. Define $d(x,S)$ as the distance from *x* to *S*. Define $f(x) = 0$ if $d(x,S)$ is rational and $f(x) = d(x,S)$ if $d(x,S)$ is irrational. Since $d(x,S)$ is continuous and is zero precisely on *S*, our *f* works.
3. We can combine the above two tricks to handle *S* locally closed, i.e., the intersection of an open and a closed set.

I suspect that the set of possible *S*es that arise as the sets of continuity form a $\sigma$-algebra. Is this true? If it is (or perhaps through some other method) we could probably show that all Borel sets are of this form.

[ADDED: For instance, there is the famous example of the function that is $1/n$ on all rationals with denominator $n$ in simplified form and $0$ on all irrationals -- that is an example of a function that is continuous only on the irrationals.]

Assuming the axiom of choice, and allowing non-measurable functions, can we get *every* possible subset of the reals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sets which arise as the points of continuity of a real-to-real function are precisely the $G_{\delta}$ sets.

I think the constructive direction only makes use of Borel sets, so the answer to the variant should be the same.

Comment: Could you give a proof or reference? Also, is your statement true for real-valued functions on any domain, or only in the case that the domain is the reals or something realistic?

Comment: I learned this fact in basic measure theory,but Gerald Itzkowitz,the instructor,used his own notes. I'd bet it's discussed in Angus Taylor's GENERAL THEORY OF FUNCTIONS AND INTEGRATION-my favorite reference for all-things real variables.

Answer (score 6):

From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-delta_set) for $G_{\delta}$ sets:

> A key property of $G_{\delta}$ sets is that they are the possible sets at which a function from a topological space to a metric space is continuous. Formally:
>   The set of points where a function $f$ is continuous is a $G_{\delta}$ set.
>   This is because continuity at a point $p$ can be defined by a $\Pi_2^0$  formula, namely:
>
> For all positive integers $n$, there is an open set $U$ containing $p$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) < 1 / n$ for all $x,y$ in $U$.
>
> If a value of $n$ is fixed, the set of $p$ for which there is such a corresponding open $U$ is itself an open set (being a union of open sets), and the universal quantifier on $n$ corresponds to the (countable) intersection of these sets.
>
> In the real line, the converse holds as well; for any $G_{\delta}$ subset $A$ of the real line, there is a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous exactly at the points in $A$.
>
> As a consequence, while it is possible for the irrationals to be the set of continuity points of a function (see the popcorn function), it is impossible to construct a function which is continuous only on the rational numbers.