# Real valued function whose derivative is nowhere continuous?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it possible that $f$ has a derivative that nowhere continuous on its domain? Please provide an example if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I would say "no".  $f$ is continuous, and that derivative is therefore of first Baire class.  Such a function is continuous except on a set of first category.

Now I'll investigate Pietro's reference and see where (or if) I went wrong.
 **(checked)**  In fact, Pompeiu's derivative is continuous on a dense $G_\delta$
set (where it vanishes) after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a proof for this? Or, perhaps a link to it? I am not very familiar with Baire category theory. However, if it is the only way to prove it, then I'm grateful if anyone could show me.

Comment: To say that a function is continuous on a set $D$ could mean either (1) that its restriction to $D$ is continuous or (2) that the whole function (not restricted) is continuous at each point of $D$ (i.e., for all $x\in D$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that, for all $y$ within $\delta$ of $x$ etc. --- whether or not $y\in D$).  The result about functions of the first Baire class uses (1), but it's plausible that the OP intended (2).

Comment: @Andreas: See answer and references here ... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32033/ 