# antiderivative of a darboux function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

this is probably a very common question, but i couldn't find the answer on my books.
is every darboux function the derivative of a function? even the nowhere continuous ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Unfortunately, there is no such simple criterion for a derivative.  At least none is known.

Ref: Bruckner, Andrew, Differentiation of real functions. Second edition. CRM Monograph Series, 5. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1994. xii+195 pp. ISBN: 0-8218-6990-6,  MR1274044 (94m:26001)

Comment: thanks, that's what i feared. i'll get the *Bruckner* asap. i think it's necessary to assume that the function is at least $L^1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\phi(x)=x\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)+\text{sgn}(x)\chi_{[-1,1]^c}(x)$, $f$ be the [Conway base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function), then $\phi\circ f$ is a Darboux function and is nowhere continuous. Moreover, $\phi\circ f$ is Borel measurable and bounded (in particular, it is $L^1$).

But $\phi\circ f$ is not a derivative because any derivative is a limit of continuous functions, hence its discontinuity points form a set of first category (in particular cannot be the whole interval). See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88271/real-valued-function-whose-derivative-is-nowhere-continuous).

In sum, $\phi\circ f$ is a bounded Borel measurable Darboux function but is not a derivative.